# Postgres: How to declare date datatype without timezone?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes, greenplum

Creating a table like:

```
create table stg.kv_test(test_date date);

insert into stg.kv_test values ('2015-07-02');

select * from stg.kv_test
```

Gives output:

```
test_date
2015-07-02 00:00:00
```

I executed above query in Aginity Workbench.

My questions are the following:

- In Postgres, does the date data type always get declared with the
  time zone part?
- How is it stored in the database?
- Is there something wrong with the Workbench I am using to query which
  is appending the timezone in output?

Comment: `date` never has a timezone. My guess would be that your SQL client displays it like that.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly just to clarify, I think you mean the "time of day part", not "time zone part". The field you created and the result you got do not include time zone info.

I think your query tool is choosing to display the date with the time part. Internally [PostgreSQL stores the date type without time](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html).

This is what I get using the psql tool here:

```
select now()::date;
    now     
------------
 2015-07-03
(1 row)
```

as opposed to:

```
select now()::timestamp;
            now             
----------------------------
 2015-07-03 02:32:15.965677
(1 row)
```

So it's probably Aginity. As far as I know what Aginity (or any other sql client) gets back will be the raw data - how it gets converted to text will be up to the client. See what happens if you use the explicit cast to `::date` above.

If you want the query to control how the text is presented, do the conversion to text in your query using [formatting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html) to control the output. Eg:

```
select to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  to_char   
------------
 2015-07-03
(1 row)
```

Note that the type of column returned above is of type 'text' whereas the other ones are 'date' or 'timestamp'.